# ANT FTP upload file: 425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out

Tags: ant, ftp

I try to automate the deployment of a small site via ANT FTP. I use Win7-64bit and what started as an easy task gets more and more a challenge.
I first figured out that I had to install additional classes which I did. `commons-net-3.0.1.jar, jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar` Then I had to deactivate parts of my firewall which I also did. `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable` But even now it is not working.

But step by step, that is the **task**:

```
<target name="ftp" description="">
<ftp server="${ftp.server}"
     userid="${ftp.user}"
     password="${ftp.password}"
     verbose="yes">
    <fileset dir="..">
        <include name="maintenance.php"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
</target>
```

Thats the **result**:

```
ftp:
  [ftp] sending files
  [ftp] transferring C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenance.php

BUILD FAILED
C:\xampp\htdocs\xdf\build.xml:32: could not put file: 425 Unable to build data con
nection: Connection timed out


Total time: 3 minutes 10 seconds
```

What the heck did I do wrong?

**UPDATE found a working example for Zend auto-sync seams ANT 1.8.3 has new features:**

```
<property name="ftp.server" value="ftp.foo.bar"/>
<property name="ftp.user" value="foor"/>
<property name="ftp.password" value="bar"/>
<property name="ftp.basedir" value=""/>
<property name="ftp.verbose" value="yes"/>

<target name="ftp-upload" description="Synchronise to FTP">
        <!-- Create temp folder -->
    <tempfile prefix="ant-epp-" destdir="${java.io.tmpdir}" property="temp.file"/>
    <mkdir dir="${temp.file}"/>

        <!-- Move, rename, upload, delete 'maintenance.php' -->
    <copy file="docs/hosting/maintenance.php" tofile="${temp.file}/index.php" />
    <ftp server="${ftp.server}"
            userid="${ftp.user}"
            password="${ftp.password}"
            remotedir="${ftp.basedir}/public"
            passive="yes"
            binary="yes"
            verbose="${ftp.verbose}">
        <fileset dir="${temp.file}">
            <include name="index.php" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
    <delete dir="${temp.file}" />

        <!-- Remove 'application' & Reupload -->
    <ftp action="del" server="${ftp.server}" userid="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}"
            remotedir="${ftp.basedir}/application" passive="yes" binary="yes" verbose="${ftp.verbose}">
        <fileset>
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
    <ftp action="rmdir" server="${ftp.server}" userid="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}"
            remotedir="${ftp.basedir}/application" passive="yes" binary="yes" verbose="${ftp.verbose}">
        <fileset>
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
    <ftp server="${ftp.server}" userid="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}"
            remotedir="${ftp.basedir}/application" passive="yes" binary="yes" verbose="${ftp.verbose}">
        <fileset dir="application" />
    </ftp>

        <!-- Replace 'index.php' -->
    <ftp server="${ftp.server}" userid="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}"
            remotedir="${ftp.basedir}/public" passive="yes" binary="yes" verbose="${ftp.verbose}">
        <fileset dir="public">
            <include name="index.php" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

Comment: Is an ftp connection possible with any other third party program?

Comment: It was not planed to use something else but because of my frustration level I now think about a PHP script. Because it is a PHP based project.

Comment: I agree with @FailedDev, you should try to get file with help of another tool (FileZilla, for example)

Comment: What FailedDev said is a classical approach to solve the problem. Since your FTP task in Ant doesn't work, you should check if other FTP softwares work or not. If they work, then try to examine the difference between Ant and FTP (like how your firewall treats them).

Comment: Thanks guys, I tryed this allready WinSCP works like a charm and my second approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022431/php-ftp-upload-problems-with-depth works to a certain point. So it is not a gernerel FTP problem. It has to do with ANT or the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that you still have a firewall issue.

Where FTP goes through a firewall, it is generally helpful to use [passive mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview).

Many FTP clients (Filezilla to take one example of many) default to passive mode.

The [Ant FTP Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) defaults to active mode:

> **passive**   selects passive-mode ("yes") transfers, for better
>   through-firewall connectivity, at the price of performance. Defaults
>   to "no"

Try using `passive="yes"` in your Ant FTP task.

Quite a good explanation [here](http://www.cknotes.com/?p=183):

> **425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out**
>
> This error can happen when trying to transfer a file or list a
>   directory in Active (PORT) mode. The problem is usually solved by
>   switching to Passive mode...
>
> Explanation of the problem: In Active mode, the data connection is
>   setup like this: The client sends a PORT command telling the server
>   the port where it will be listening for the data connection. The
>   server receives the PORT command and initiates a connection to the
>   client's IP/port. However, if a firewall is blocking the incoming
>   connection, then it will go unanswered, and the server will timeout
>   waiting for the connection to be accepted.

I'm no firewall expect, but I *think* that the command you executed to configure your firewall (`netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable`) is what you would do if you wanted to run an FTP *server* on your Windows box behind a firewall. In your case, I think you are connecting from Windows as a client to a remote FTP server, so I think you could undo that command.

Comment: Thank you, it is working! So I can now activate my firewall again if I understand the technique the right way?

Comment: Glad it works. I have updated my answer in response to your question.

Comment: It seam `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable` is needed even if I use passiv mode. Just to clear this up.